# How to know that in QTP/UFT which add-in's were used in any random test project?

Tags: testing, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, qtplugin

Here the situation is that I have a already tested project and I Don't know that which add-ins is being used in that tested project so my question is that how can I know which add-in is used in that test project using that test script to prepare the test environment  ?

Answer (score 3):

You can get that info using QTP/UFT Automation Object Model.

```
Set QTP = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
arrAddins = QTP.GetAssociatedAddinsForTest(testPath)
```

Ref:

http://helpfiles.intactcloud.com/QTP/11.00/QTP11-00_AutomationObjectModel/QuickTest~Application~GetAssociatedAddinsForTest.html

Answer (score 2):

You can open the test and then you can check and modify the add-in’s for opened test from **“File-Settings-Properties”**.

Other things you can do with Add-in Manager are shown in below link

http://www.ufthelp.com/2013/04/understanding-add-in-manager-in-uft.html

Check the **Important** section of that link to see the screenshot of the option that I have specified.